# File and Printer Sharing showing different results

Tags: windows, networking, file-sharing, windows-server

On our domain there is a computer A with ***Windows Server 2022*** operating system. My computer B has ***Windows 10*** operating system.

I made remote desktop connection to computer A.

There I check the "File and printer sharing" setting for domain via ***Control Panel*** app and it is showing that `Turn off file and printer sharing` radio button is selected. So it is off.

But then I open ***PowerShell*** and run `Get-NetAdapterBinding` command and it is showing "File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks" is `enabled`.

What is the reason? I cannot understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Almost for sure there is a Server Group Policy enabling File and Printer Sharing.

File and Printer Sharing would normally be enabled on a domain connected workstation.

This will also override the workstation setting. Another way of saying this is that a workstation setting cannot normally override a Server Group Policy.